# During the calculation of mean of a column in dataframe that contain missing values

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-science, missing-data

Let's take an example.
suppose we have a data frame that has column name "f1"

> f1 : {2, 4, NaN, 1, NaN, 15}

and when we apply mean imputation to it then we write a code like this

```
dataframe['f1'].fillna(dataframe['f1'].mean())
```

so my doubt is when it computes the mean of f1 during **dataframe['f1'].mean()** I know that it excludes the NaN value during summation(in the numerator) because they can't be added but what I want to know is it can be included or excluded in the denominator when dividing by the total number of values.

mean is computes like this

> mean(f1) = (2+4+1+15)/6(include NaN in total number of values)

or this way

> mean(f1) = (2+4+1+15)/4(exclude NaN in total number of values)

also, explain why?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official documentation of pandas.DataFrame.mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) "skipna" parameter excludes the NA/null values. If it was excluded from numerator but denominator this would be exclusively mentioned in the documentation. You could prove yourself that it is excluded from denominator by performing a simple experimentation with a dummy dataframe such as the one you have examplified in the question.

The reason NA/null values should be excluded from denominator is about being statistically correct. Mean is the sum of the numbers divided by total number of them. If you could not add a value to the summation, then it is pointless to make an extra count in the denominator for it. If you count it in the denominator, it equals behaving as though the NA/null value was 0. However, the value is not 0, it is unknown, unobserved, hidden etc.

If you are acknowledged about the nature of the distribution in practice, you could [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) or [fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna) NA/null values accordingly with the nature of the distribution, then take the mean of all the values. For instance, if you realize that the feature in question has a linear nature, you could interpolate missing values with "linear" approach.

Answer (score 2):

[`pd.Series.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html) calculates the mean only for non-NaN values, so for above data, mean is `(2+4+1+15)/4=5.5`, 4 is the number of non-NaN values, this is the default behavior for calculating `mean`. If you want to include the mean for the given Series using all the rows for denominator, you can `fillna(0)` before calling `mean()`:

Calling `mean()` directly:

```py
df['f1'].fillna(df['f1'].mean())
0     2.0
1     4.0
2     5.5   <------
3     1.0
4     5.5   <------
5    15.0
Name: f1, dtype: float64
```

calling `mean()` after `fillna(0)`:

```py
df['f1'].fillna(df['f1'].fillna(0).mean())
0     2.000000
1     4.000000
2     3.666667   <------
3     1.000000
4     3.666667   <------
5    15.000000
Name: f1, dtype: float64
```